# How to identify standalone spheres in Julia?

Tags: julia, cluster-analysis, dbscan, plots.jl

How is it possible to get rid of standalone spheres? Or how can I manipulate the data set, that I don't plot spheres, which are not connected together? (Means the surface of a sphere does't touch another sphere)
In the example there are some spheres which aren't connected to the main pile. The data set includes x-,y-,z-coordinates and the volume of each sphere.

Thank you,
Tom

[image: example plot of spheres]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are asking for is called [anomaly detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) and it is not a problem of plotting a graph but a family of algorithms for analyzing multidimensional data.

There are many approaches to this problem but perhaps you could start by looking at: https://github.com/milanflach/MultivariateAnomalies.jl

Another approach would be to use a clustering method (see https://github.com/JuliaStats/Clustering.jl) such as DBSCAN, and then interpret small clusters and anomalies, for discussion see here https://towardsdatascience.com/best-clustering-algorithms-for-anomaly-detection-d5b7412537c8.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try tomorrow. Cheers

Comment: DB-SCAN with a proper radius should do exactly what you need as Przemyslaw suggested. Or you might create a graph and find a giant connected component in it using LightGraphs.jl.